# Fix 'ERROR - Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID'

Tags: localhost

My program is working fine but seems I have to set 'set localhost'.

Should I do this or it's optional?
How to fix in case I should?

```
-sh-4.1$ sh interproscan.sh -i test_proteins.fasta -f tsv -goterms
30/05/2016 14:42:21:909 Welcome to InterProScan-5.18-57.0
2016-05-30 14:42:28,084 [main] [net.sf.ehcache.Cache:216] ERROR - Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: Covoserver: Covoserver: unknown error
java.net.UnknownHostException: Covoserver: Covoserver: unknown error
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1484)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<clinit>(Cache.java:214)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:296)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createDefaultCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:219)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:722)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:439)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:377)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:259)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1037)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:1013)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:998)
    at org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.java:139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at uk.ac.ebi.interpro.scan.management.model.implementations.writer.GraphicalOutputResultWriter.setApplicationContextConfigLocation(GraphicalOutputResultWriter.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl$BeanPropertyHandler.setValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:454)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at uk.ac.ebi.interpro.scan.jms.main.Run.main(Run.java:178)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Covoserver: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1479)
    ... 68 more
30/05/2016 14:42:29:640 Running InterProScan v5 in STANDALONE mode...
30/05/2016 14:42:43:800 Loading file /home/bernardo/Databases/my_interproscan/interproscan-5.18-57.0/test_proteins.fasta
30/05/2016 14:42:43:805 Running the following analyses:
[PIRSF-3.01,Pfam-29.0,PRINTS-42.0,ProSiteProfiles-20.119,PANTHER-10.0,Coils-2.2.1,Hamap-201511.02,ProSitePatterns-20.119,SUPERFAMILY-1.75,ProDom-2006.1,SMART-7.1,Gene3D-3.5.0,TIGRFAM-15.0]
Available matches will be retrieved from the pre-calculated match lookup service.

Matches for any sequences that are not represented in the lookup service will be calculated locally.
30/05/2016 14:42:45:374 29% completed
30/05/2016 14:42:50:666 57% completed
30/05/2016 14:42:56:783 86% completed
30/05/2016 14:43:01:933 100% done:  InterProScan analyses completed
```

Comment: Your best bet is to seek help from the [developer](http://www.ehcache.org/) of that component.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:Open your hosts file:

```
vim /etc/hosts
```

Step 2:Add dns resolv

```
127.0.0.1 Covoserver
```

Hope this could solve your problem,it works in my machine.